# Is it overkill to create separate AppDomains just to have isolated config files? Any alternatives?

Tags: .net, appdomain

I am building a server application that will have different modules, which are essentially sets of functionality providing various endpoints for communication.

For example,

Module 1 - WCF endpoints

Module 2 - WCF endpoints

I would really like to have isolated configuration files per module.  This way, if two modules are using WCF to host various endpoints, the configurations for each module can be in separate files.

I am considering creating separate AppDomains for each module to allow this.  Is this overkill?  Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Can you just set up multiple IIS sites? This will also result in multiple AppDomains, but in an easier way.

Comment: I did just that, when creating a self hosting service host for multiple WCF services. If you require the separation, than that I you only viable option.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have each endpoint have a string that is appended to the config key, and from there reference the keys with that string appended

String WCFName = "Service1";

Then get the config key configKeyName + WCFName